Guy lives in dumpy hotel in turn of century Los Angeles
I'm trying to think of a movie I saw a few years back. It is about a writer or a detective, he moves to L.A. before it was a major city and lives in a dumpy hotel room. He has run ins with a beautiful girl. The entire movie is about him writing and his experiences in L.A. before it turns into Hollywood. I cannot think of who is in it.

Could be Barton Fink, apart from the "turn of the century" bit.

Might be Ask the Dust with Colin Farrell and Salma Hayek. Farrell plays an aspiring writer in Depression-era Los Angeles. He befriends and falls in love with a waitress (Hayek) who is in love with another. The character lives in a hotel in a run-down part of town.

I think it is Ask the Dust! I've never seen Barton Fink, so it's not that. Thanks everyone!

@Brulia If this is the correct answer, please approve it by clicking on the check mark. This effectively 'closes' the question.

I'm with +Fruitbat, who commented on your post. The movie sounds like Barton Fink except that it takes place in 1941. From IMDB:

In 1941, New York intellectual playwright Barton Fink comes to Hollywood to write a Wallace Beery wrestling picture. Staying in the eerie Hotel Earle, Barton develops severe writer's block. His neighbor, jovial insurance salesman Charlie Meadows, tries to help, but Barton continues to struggle as a bizarre sequence of events distracts him even further from his task.

There is also a beautiful woman who may or may not be seen in a framed photo he has.
 
